# error: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 after upgrading ruby 1.8.7 to ruby 1.9.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, utf

I had my app running in ruby 1.8.7 and rails 3.0.11 ,I upgraded it with 1.9.2 ruby and rails 3.2.2.
it has a utf convertor like this

```
@utf8_converter = Iconv.new('UTF-8//IGNORE', 'UTF-8')
......  
......
def utf8(untrusted_string)
valid_string = @utf8_converter.iconv(untrusted_string + ' ')[0..-2]
return valid_string
```

Unto my Understanding Iconv doesn't support ruby 1.9.2.
how can make it run?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is should get you on the right track:

```
def utf8(untrusted_string) 
  valid_string = (untrusted_string + ' ').encode('utf-8')
  return valid_string
end
```

The `@utf8_converter` variable is no longer needed as Iconv is deprecated, so you can get away with just your utf8 method.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby 1.9.2 does support [Iconv](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/iconv/rdoc/Iconv.html), if you are using ruby through rvm, you should install it in the following way,

```
$ rvm pkg install iconv
$ rvm reinstall 1.9.2 --with-iconv-dir=$rvm_path/usr
```

Read more [here](http://beginrescueend.com/packages/iconv/)